# Is it possible to move the entire vector layer in Openlayer?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openstreetmap

I have a vector layer which consist of multiple feature layers. I want them all to move so that it will fit to my based layer which is the OSM.
[image: Vector Layer]

As you noticed, it doesn't fit with the based map/layer..I want it to move by a certain points or re-position it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by myself, in case someone experiences the same problem. Here's the code:

```
 for (var i=0; i < layer_agao.features.length; i++){
            var featselect = layer_agao.features[i];
            featselect.geometry.move(13,4);
        }
```

"layer_agao" is your vector layer."13,4" are the values for x and y coordinate.